# How do I build WHL packages after changing the code?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I added some log codes in grpc/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf code, to help locate the problem, i install grpc python from source, but The change did not take effect. Please give me some advice, thanks.

**Supported Python Versions**

Python 3.7.9

**What operating system (Linux, Windows,...) and version?**

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

**What did you do?**

I added some log codes in grpc/third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf code， then i compiled protobuf , compiled grpc and install grpc python from source

```
mkdir -p "third_party/protobuf/cmake/build"
cd  "third_party/protobuf/cmake/build"
cmake -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make -j14 install
popd
make -j14
```

i  modified setup.py, add this code:

```
CORE_C_FILES = filter(lambda x: 'third_party/protobuf' not in x, CORE_C_FILES)
PROTOBUF_INCLUDE = (os.path.join('/usr', 'include', 'protobuf'),)
EXTENSION_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES = ((PYTHON_STEM,) + CORE_INCLUDE + ABSL_INCLUDE +
                                 ADDRESS_SORTING_INCLUDE + CARES_INCLUDE +
                                 RE2_INCLUDE + PROTOBUF_INCLUDE + SSL_INCLUDE + UPB_INCLUDE +
                                 UPB_GRPC_GENERATED_INCLUDE +
                                 UPBDEFS_GRPC_GENERATED_INCLUDE +
                                 XXHASH_INCLUDE + ZLIB_INCLUDE)
```

then i run:

```
pip install -rrequirements.txt
GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_WITH_CYTHON=1 pip install .
```

**I'm confused, why aren't the changes to Protobuf working? Maybe there is something wrong with my installation method, please give me some suggestions,thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [the grpc-io thread](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/-DCwf3zTwBM):

> The grpcio package doesn't actually depend on protobuf. Only generated code (i.e. _pb2.py and _pb2_grpc.py) have this dependency. Instead, you'll want to build the protobuf wheel from the protobuf repository and use that alongside an off-the-shelf grpcio wheel.

> Also, to answer the obvious follow-up question: "Why do we have a vendored protobuf directory in our repo at all then?". The grpcio-tools wheel does build in the libprotobuf native code to generate the aforementioned _pb2.py and _pb2_grpc.py files.